# How can I rotate a UITextField 90 degree so text is vertical?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I've got a UITextField and I want to rotate it so the text is vertical. This is a 90 degree rotation anti clockwise.

How can I do this in the interface builder so I can line it up properly with my other assets?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible with Interface Builder. You can, however do it in code. Use the following call on your text view in viewDidLoad:

```
[aTextView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90* M_PI/180)];
```

You may have to play with the frame some to get it positioned just right. Also, the internal coordinate system of the view will be rotated as well.

Comment: Thanks, I guess i'll have to use trial and error to get it lined up correctly.